# C# Unit Test project against WebApi with Owin

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2, owin

My goal is to run a test in Visual Studio against my web API. I'm trying to call the controller as I saw somewhere on the web.

```
var controller = new PriceFeedController();

dynamic item = controller.Get(1, 1);

controller.Post(new PostPriceFeed { Item_Id = 1, Store_Id = 1, Price = decimal.Parse(item.pricefeed.price) + 10 });
dynamic itemprice_updated = controller.Get(1, 1);
Assert.AreEqual(decimal.Parse(item.pricefeed.price), decimal.Parse(itemprice_updated.pricefeed.price));
```

The main problem is about the OWIN. My controller starts with something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get(long storeId, long itemId)
{
    //busco o id do usuário
    var user_id = SessionState.GetUserIDByContext(Request.GetRequestContext());
    //...
}
```

And when I try to run the test, the `Request` is null and I get an error.
Do someone know a tutorial on how to do what I want?

**EDIT**

After @Peter tip, I can insert a Request but my claim is not there.

```
 ClaimsPrincipal principal = httpRequestContext.Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;
        return long.Parse(principal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "user_id").Single().Value);
```

The "user_id" does not exist, but I'm passing the token.

Comment: I'm using the Bearer Token btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the Request property of the Controller explicitly during initialization. Once the Controller has a Request, you can add properties that will be available from the Controller action.

If you're using the Request properties for authentication, more steps are required to handle that securely (see [Securing and securely calling Web API and [Authorize]](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/martinkearn/2015/03/25/securing-and-securely-calling-web-api-and-authorize/) for an example with API tokens)

```
var controller = new PriceFeedController {Request = new HttpRequestMessage()};
controller.Request.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey,
    new HttpConfiguration());

controller.Request.Properties.Add("sample_property",
    "plaintext string to pass to Get() method on PriceFeed");

var result = controller.Get(100, 105);
```

Comment: Nice tip @Peter thanks! I'm almost there, the only problem is in the controller. After the Request when I tried to retrieve my user_id claim! The claim created when I generate my bearer token does not exists. But when I use the api in any app it works fines.

Comment: You will need to create a ClaimsPrincipal with the proper claims and set the User property of the controller to that object.  Honestly though, you should mark this answer as the accepted answer and ask another if there are more problems.